# Property not found on type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127 when using implements Serializable

Tags: java, spring, jsf, tomcat, serialization

i have **view bean** as follows:

```
    @Named("myBean")
    @Scope(ScopeType.VIEW)
    public class MyBean implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1635565383922455897L;

            List<CompanyValue> values = new ArrayList<CompanyValue>(6);

        public List<CompanyValue> getValues() {
            return values;
        }

        public void setValues(List<CompanyValue> values) {
            this.values = values;
        }
}
```

i am using spring scope annotation

and the jsf code is as follows:

```
<h:inputText value="#{companyValueBean.values[0].name}" />
```

the CompanyValue domain class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_value")
public class CompanyValue implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2966293162153602542L;

    }

    @Column(name = "name", length = 25)
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and i am getting exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: mypage.xhtml @34,195 value="#{MyBean.values[0].name}": Property 'values' not found on type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this error disappears when i remove `implements Serializable` from my view bean.
please advise why i am getting this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Which `@Scope` annotation are you using?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, spring

Comment: Does `CompanyValue` have a public `name` field?

Comment: Please give the exact package it belongs to.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, i posted code for CompanyValue domain class

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, it is in package `org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to add CGLIB to your classpath and change

```
@Scope(ScopeType.VIEW)
```

to

```
@Scope(ScopeType.VIEW, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

As to why this happens, Spring uses, by default, JDK proxies to proxy your beans. The JDK proxies it creates only implement the interfaces your bean's class implements, not its actual class type. In other words, the proxy for `MyBean`, which for this run is `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127`, would implement only `Serializable`, but would not be of type `MyBean`.

Furthermore, EL resolution is done by calling `getClass()` on the object it's trying to resolve the property on, and using reflection to get the getter `Method`. In this case, the class `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127` (or the interfaces it implements, ie. `Serializable`) does not have a `getValues()` method.

CGLIB proxies on the other hand do extend the base class so you do have access to methods declared in that class. `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` forces Spring to use CGLIB proxies.

As to why it works when you remove `Serializable`...maybe Spring again defaults to CGLIB if your bean class doesn't implement any interfaces.

Comment: i will try that but can you tell me why i got this exception and why i need to use the proxyMode solution, i have lots of view beans scoped by spring and implements serializable but only this bean gives exception and i am curious to know the reason and should i do that for all my view beans scoped by spring ?

Comment: @MahmoudS Do your other bean classes implement any interfaces? It also depends the properties you are trying to access.

Comment: all my view beans are scoped by spring like this one and also implements serializeble like this one too, so should i make all my beans use above solution to avoid future problems ?

Comment: @MahmoudS I would say yes.